# Excel VBA Workbook_BeforeClose with shared workbook

Tags: excel, vba

we currently have a code in one of our Excel workbooks that when the workbook is closed, Sheet1 is protected with a password.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     Sheets("Sheet1").Protect "XYZ"
     ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

This works fine, but these workbooks often have more than 1 employee working in them. If one of these employees closes the workbook, it is locked while the other one is still working in it.

Is it possible to create a query that checks if someone else is still in the Workbook? If this is the case, the lock should not take place.

Unfortunately I could not find a solution that works..

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You might want to check out this article and it's links to make sure you are taking full advantage of the builtin features of shared workbooks. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/excel-shared-file-can-be-accessed-by-multiple/10a74b74-b96a-4b49-ad8b-ec227db3ce56

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately I could not find anything there that could help with our problem situation. It is intended that colleagues can work in the table at the same time. Read-Only is not needed.